# Sorting a list of strings based on numeric order of numeric part

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of strings that may contain digits. I would like to sort this list alphabetically, but every time the String contains a number, I want it to be sorted by value.
For example, if the list is

```
['a1a','b1a','a10a','a5b','a2a'],
```

the sorted list should be

```
['a1a','a2a','a5b','a10a','b1a']
```

In general I want to treat each number (a sequence of digits) in the string as a special character, which is smaller than any letter and can be compared numerically to other numbers.

Is there any python function which does this compactly?

Comment: How would you compare `'ab1c'` and `'a1ef'`?

Comment: assuming numbers are smaller than letters I would compare the character '1' with the letter 'b' and put 'a1ef' before 'ab1c'.

In general I want to look at each number in the string as a special character, which is smaller than any letter and can be compared numerically to other numbers.

Comment: Can't you use `mylist.sort()` method ?

Comment: No, sort will put 'a2a' after 'a10a' although 10 is larger than 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `re` module to split each string into a tuple of characters and grouping the digits into one single element. Something like `r'(\d+)|(.)'`. The good news with this regex is that it will return separately the numeric and non numeric groups.

As a simple key, we could use:

```
def key(x):
    # the tuple comparison will ensure that numbers come before letters
    return [(j, int(i)) if i != '' else (j, i)
        for i, j in re.findall(r'(\d+)|(.)', x)]
```

Demo:

```
lst = ['a1a', 'a2a', 'a5b', 'a10a', 'b1a', 'abc']
print(sorted(lst, key=key)
```

gives:

```
['a1a', 'a2a', 'a5b', 'a10a', 'abc', 'b1a']
```

If you want a more efficient processing, we could compile the regex only once in a closure

```
def build_key():
    rx = re.compile(r'(\d+)|(.)')
    def key(x):
        return [(j, int(i)) if i != '' else (j, i)
            for i, j in rx.findall(x)]
    return key
```

and use it that way:

```
sorted(lst, key=build_key())
```

giving of course the same output.